# For an hourly data, Getting maximum value for each day

Tags: r

Let I have the following data :

```
time <- seq(ISOdate(2007,7,1,0), ISOdate(2008,4,5,23), by = "1 hour")
y <- rnorm(n = length(time))

year  <- as.numeric(substr((as.character(time)), 1, 4))  # year number as numeric

month <- as.numeric(substr((as.character(time)), 6, 7))  # month number as numeric

day <- as.numeric(substr((as.character(time)), 9, 10))  # day number as numeric

hour <- as.numeric(substr((as.character(time)), 12, 13))  # hour number as numeric

dat <- data.frame(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=hour, y = y)
```

For each day, there are 24 `y` values at each hour(0 to 23). Now I have to find maximum of `y` for each day. That is, say, for the date "2007-10-05" there are 24 `y` values obtained in each hour (0 to 23) and I have to get the maximum value for the day "2007-10-05". Hence since there are 279 days between "2007-07-01" to "2008-04-05", I will get 279 maximum `y` values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
dyp1 <- dat %>% 
        group_by(year, month, day) %>% 
        summarise(y=max(y))
```

Using `data.table`,

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, .(y=max(y)), by = .(year, month, day)]
```

Using base `R`,

```
aggregate( y ~ year+month+day, dat, max)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select year, month, day, 
       max(y) as y 
       from dat 
       group by year, month, day")
```

---

Or another option would be to order 'y' and select the first value

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[order(-y), .(y= y[1L]), by = .(year, month, day)]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(year, month, day) %>%
    arrange(desc(y)) %>%
    summarise(y = first(y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply the cut command directly to the time and y array:

```
tapply(y, INDEX =cut(time, breaks="day"), max)
```

or using the dplyr library:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-data.frame(time, y)
summarize(group_by(df, cut(df$time, breaks="day")), max(y))
```